# Would GMail block mail sent from their own IP addresses?

Tags: gmail, blacklist

I have been checking our site's email messages at http://www.mail-tester.com today to make sure we're not sending messages considered "spammy."  All was well with several of our messages.  Great!

But then I had to send an email from my GMail account to mail-tester.com.  The message and subject of the email are generated from our site, and I wanted to make sure it's content wasn't "spammy," either.

The results (see image) surprised me, and now make me wonder:  Has Gmail been blocking their own mail sent to my GMail account simply because their own sending IP addresses get blacklisted?

I've occasionally seen emails blocked by our SendGrid service that should get forwarded to my GMail account with a "550 5.7.1" reason.  Now I have to wonder if they're blocked because they were sent through blacklisted GMail IP addresses.  Am I totally off-base here?

[image: mail-tester.com spam test results - mail sent FROM my Gmail account]

**UPDATE:**

Since there's been no response here or on Google's product forums, I'm now offering a 50 point bounty.  It's as if I either asked the Wrong Question (as in "don't look behind the Google curtain!"), or it's wholly unknowable.  At least it earned me that coveted Tumbleweed badge I've been hoping for!  :/

Answer (score 1):

Google doesn't make it very clear when they will or won't block IP's or emails but Google's policy is to automate everything as much as possible. This can create some problems sometimes. Awhile back google alerts was used for spam. https://robert.accettura.com/blog/2007/06/20/google-used-for-spam/ things like this happen from time to time. When it does, Gmail blocks their own emails for while even when they are legitimate.
Personal experience: One of my own google alerts was being marked as spam for awhile even though I created it, it was sent to myself, and I wanted it. the email that was being blocked was: googlealerts-noreply@google.com

Comment: Appreciate the feedback.  Would like a more definite answer, but this does at least tell me it's not impossible, and that I'm not asking the Stupidest Question Ever on Webmaster's SE.

Comment: I think you question is interesting. I think it will be very hard to get a definite answer about google. Since no one else answered I decided to share my personal experience hoping that would help. I hope you get a definite answer.